# python: json print root object names

Tags: python, json, json-deserialization

I have a JSON String like this:

```json
{
  "Sommersprossen": {
    "count": 5,
    "lastSeenTime": 1586959168567
  },
  "inkognito": {
    "count": 7,
    "lastSeenTime": 1586901586361
  },
  "Marienkäfer": {
    "count": 7,
    "lastSeenTime": 1586958264090,
    "difficulty": 0.8902439024390244,
    "difficultyWeight": 82
  },
  "Zaun": {
    "count": 8,
    "lastSeenTime": 1586958848320
  },
```

Now I want to print something like this: `Sommersprossen, inkognito, Marienkäfer, Zaun`. 
But I don't know how to...
My existing Python code is:

```py
url = "https://skribbliohints.github.io/German.json"

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

data = json.loads(response.read())
```

But the problem is I cant find a way to print the objects names.

Comment: You can simply treat it as dictionary and print its Keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A json is essentially just a dictionary. You can access it like any other python dictionary.

```
url = "https://skribbliohints.github.io/German.json"

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

data = json.loads(response.read())

roots = list(data.keys())
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i wanted!

Answer (score 0):

You can treat this json output as dictionary and print its Keys, for this exapmle you can simply perform it with:

```
data.keys()
```

Output:

```
dict_keys(['Sommersprossen', 'inkognito', 'Marienkäfer', 'Zaun'])
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s a dict, so you can do:

```
“, “.join(data.keys())
```